# Vue Dirty state triggering in component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page in Vue with input fields. I wanna show a message when someone changed any input field in that component. I'm used to Angular where you can use the isDirty function, but Vue doesn't have that.

Is there a way to catch all keyup events in a Vue view?
So I can catch that and set a variable to true for the message to be shown?

Now I have this added to all input models: 
`<input v-model="foo" @change="someThingChanged()">`

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a way to catch all keyup events in a Vue view?

You can bind single `onchange` event on the parent container and benefit from the fact that change events bubble:

```
<div class="container" @change="someThingChanged()">
  <input v-model="foo">
  <input v-model="bar">
  ... etc.
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Same goes for `@input` which already triggers while typing. Note that (at least for PrimeVue 3) events for Dropdown somehow don't seem to bubble up.

Comment: Keep in mind that `change` events emitted by Vue do NOT bubble, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861657/vue-js-emit-native-dom-events)

Answer (score 3):

I am not that experienced in Vue but [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) seems preferable here.

```
 watch: {
 item: {
    handler(val){
      // do stuff
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from checking for dirty, We can also use Component Navigation guards to prevent user from navigating elsewhere if the form is dirty.
[BeforerouteLeave Vue Component route gaurd](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).

```
...
data: {
  formDirty: false, 
}
methods: {
  somethingchanged() {
    formDirty = true,
  }
}
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  if(formDirty){
    const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!')
    if (answer) {
      return next()
    } else {
      return next(false)
    }
  }
  return next()
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of watching the DOM for key or change events, it would be better to just observe `foo` which is already in the component state.  In this case I've used a computed function based on `foo`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-wrapper',
  data: {
    foo: '',
  },
  computed: {
    showMessage() {
      return (!!this.foo) // <-- your logic here
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-wrapper">
  Foo: <input v-model="foo">
  <div v-if="showMessage">This will be shown if foo is not empty</div>
</div>
```