# Vue.JS emit native DOM events

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events

I have a custom checkbox component, which is composed by a classic checkbox and a label. You are able to click either the checkbox or the label to toggle the state.

[image]

I want to emit a native [onchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), so I can do a `v-on` listener on a distant div grandparent. The input I use for the actual checkbox is properly emitting a native `onchange` event, but I'm unable to manually emit a bubbling native `onchange` event when the label is clicked. I've tried `this.$emit('change')` and `this.$emit('onchange')`, neither which bubble like the native DOM event would.

Here is a simple example:

```html
<!-- Form.vue -->

<div id="form-1" @change="markDirty()">
  <div class="header">
    <CustomButton>Submit</CustomButton>
    <CustomButton>Cancel</CustomButton>
  </div>
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-region">
      <CustomCheckBox :checked.sync='tryChecked'>Try checking me!</CustomCheckBox>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- CustomCheckBox.vue -->

<template>
  <div class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="selectCheckbox" />
    <label v-on:click="selectCheckbox">
        <slot></slot>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'CustomCheckBox',
    props: {
        checked: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        selectCheckbox() {
            this.$emit('update:checked', !this.checked)
            this.$emit('change')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I would like to be able to tell when any element in my form has changed via `onchange` bubbling, so I can set a dirty flag. This example would be fine if I only had native buttons and checkboxes, as they emit native `onchange` events. With my `CustomCheckBox`, it bubbles when I click the actual native checkbox, but the label does not.

Is this possible in Vue? If not, what's the best way to do this with native Javascript?

Comment: is unclear what you mean by distant div grandparent an example would explain it, you could use a ref on the grandparent component to get the child instance and watch its data, then on the component which renders the checkbox you could use  `<checkbox :change="doSomthing"/>`, though if you need to watch things from afar then look into using vuex

Comment: @LawrenceCherone updated with an example. In my situation, there are many, many forms throughout the project with widely varying structures. It isn't practical to 'manually bubble' or explicitly use refs. I want something that's modular and fits the web framework style. If a native HTML element emits change events, it only figures that components should be able to too.

Comment: @Spooky Vue DOM events are completely separate from native DOM events so they will not operate 1-to-1. Look into [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/detect-html-form-changes/) article. Details the drawbacks of native onChange and how to capture a changed value using native HTML API attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Events emitted by Vue do not bubble like native events do. You need to handle the emitted event right in the parent component or utilize state, as shown here: [How to bubble events on a component subcomponent chain with Vue js 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029150/how-to-bubble-events-on-a-component-subcomponent-chain-with-vue-js-2)

You could either "bubble" the event using `v-on` handlers in every subsequent parent component, passing the event on "manually", use state via a `bus` as described in the source mentioned above or via `vuex`.

Using vanilla js would be a suboptimal solution here as you would need to set the event handler in the grandparent component directly, which would mean accessing a DOM element rendered in a child component. While this is possible, it creates interdependence among the components and should therefore be avoided when possible.

Comment: Manually bubbling isn't practical as there are many different forms throughout my project with widely varying structures. I don't want to add a `v-on:change` directive and re-emit to 5+ layers deep of divs for every single form.

Comment: As for global state, each component manages their own dirty state. I don't want page-wide dirty state. If I have multiple forms in one page, I want them to be able to individually derive their dirty state from the components within them.

Comment: The functionality already exists to bubble change events natively, it only figures that custom components should be able to emit onchange events too. I’m sure I’m not the only person using Vue who has ever made a custom input component.